# in drupal 7, views_get_view('VIEWNAME') get a error?

Tags: drupal, view

I want to embed a view in the `tpl.php`, so I am using the `views_get_view('VIEWNAME')` function.

Here is what I am doing the `tpl.php`:

```
<?php
   $view = views_get_view('MapView');  
   print $view->preview('default');
?>
```

"`MapView`" is the view's name, I am not sure the argument in the `views_get_view` is the machine name or human readable name, in fact in my example is using the human readable name, because I can't find the machine name in the drupal view configuration.

Anyway, I get a error saying "`Fatal error: Call to a member function preview() on a non-object`", seems like I didn't fetch the view in the correct?

any idea?

Comment: You do realise we have a Drupal site? http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View id you can easly get from edit view url. Like any key it consists of undescores and lowercase.
Also to output view in needed place try it:

```
$view = views_embed_view('view_id', $display_id = 'block');
print $view;
```

It worked for me for node content, i added view to the nodes of needed type in my module:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if($node->type=="type"){
  $view = views_embed_view('view_id', $display_id = 'block');
  $node->content['myfield'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<h3>Title</h3>'.$view, 
    '#weight' => 1,
  );

  return $node;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1. views_embed_view() is actually the best way to embed the View. 
However if you want to alter the View (items per page, etc), views_get_view() is the way.

Answer (score 0):

An old question but I was having the same issue and I couldn't find the right answer: you have to use the machinename and it is case sensitive! You can find it in the database in the views_view table in the "name" field.